# NSURLConnection duplicate Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, httprequest

I am using `NSURLConnection` to send request to server and receive response like this :

```
cmdConn = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req 
                                    delegate:self 
                                    startImmediately:YES] autorelease];
```

and receive the response and data in its delegates. connection `didReceiveData:(NSData *)data and connection didReceiveData:(NSURLResponse *)response`

everything works good but the problem is when I check the server side most of times (not all the times) I receive duplicate request. I checked everything in my code and also server side , it seems the problem is with `NSURLConnection` .

please help me in this problem , if you have any idea ...

Comment: please dont tell me it is for loop or other things ... cause I have already checked my code

Comment: Posting some code snippets might help.

Comment: problem is with NSURLConnection behavior , we checked the code many times and also server side , I wonder is there any call back or like that in nsurlconnection that cause duplicate send of request or not , it is not happening all the time also

Comment: You can NSLog() each connection's start to see where you send duplicate requests.

Comment: if you read the question completely you will see that I already used nslog !!!

Comment: i also face the same issue. making duplicate request from the ios device/ simulator. found any solution??

Comment: I used CFNetwork instead of NSURLConnection , but I am not sure why it is happening in NSURLConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem can be about the responses that you get and how you read them . you can also use CFHTTPMessage that is a core foundation class .

Comment: I already used CFHTTP but and the problem is about reading from the buffer